# What language is embedded in this code with <% and <%=

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded a calendar built for bootstrap at https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar, and I started to customize the pages according to my needs.
However, in several pieces of the code, there are calls to variables and methods inside <%.
With some research, at first I thought it was erb, however I tested many erb methods which don't work.
Could someone please tell me what I am dealing with, please?

```
<div class="cal-month-day <%= cls %>">
    <span class="pull-right" data-cal-date="<%= data_day %>" data-cal-view="day" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<%= tooltip %>"><%= day %></span>
    <% if (events.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="events-list" data-cal-start="<%= start %>" data-cal-end="<%= end %>">
            <% _.each(events, function(event) { %>
                <a href="<%= event.url ? event.url : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" data-event-class="<%= event['class'] %>"
                    class="pull-left event <%= event['class'] %>" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="<%= event.title %>"></a>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Also, is it possible to read some of those variables into php variables? I could use some of them as parameters for other methods in php classes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like Underscore's built in [template engine](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: +1 - It does indeed look like that, and it's confirmed as such in the readme on the linked repo.

Comment: Looks like it's in fact Underscore. Thanks. Do you know if I can somehow use the variables, such as <%= cls %>, in php methods?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with php, but I believe you can bastardize your code and interpolate it as javascript in your php code, but only on the page of course.  I did this many years ago, but do not remember the syntax. Sorry